# Globally extensive overview of rocket startup companies

Tags: rockets, business

Is there any known report, website or other source from where one can get a comprehensive overview of **almost all startup companies related to space rockets or hardware that's dedicated to space rockets**? I'm not interested in the products in particular, but in the companies/organizations that design and (intend to) build stuff.

Of course that would have to be updated rather frequently, but it sounds manageable.

I found something only about particular regions, or very outdated information. I am looking for current information that is as extensive as possible. Any definition of "startup company" is fine. Governmental/institutional (e.g. Universities) projects are also welcomed.

PS: any tag suggestions?

Comment: [The annual compendium of commercial space transportation](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/ast/media/2018_ast_compendium.pdf) by the FAA is also a great resource. There is a long list of fact sheets for different launch vehicles starting at page 106 but also a lot of other great information about the industry in the 100 pages before that.

Comment: @GittingGud one more reason to finally take a look at this. I am procrastinating since forever because of the page count xD

Answer (score 3, accepted):

New Space Hub is an invite only social network that keeps track of things like this. https://newspacehub.co/

They allow you to search their database though, even if you are not a member. So hopefully you can find what you are looking for there.

It is very well updated because most of their members are very active in the startup community.

Comment: Do you have any invitations by any chance? Would love to signup for it.

Comment: I think I have 9 left. If you want one just tell me what email to send it too.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot @Knudsen Number :D :D :D Here's my email id: 
high_flying_death_defying@outlook.com

Comment: And done. Sent it.

Answer (score 0):

At this year's IAC, there was a talk on the situation of startups developing "small launch vehicles". This excludes all launchers capable of delivering >1000kg of payload to LEO.

[image: Growth of the Small Launcher Market 2015-2018]

[[source](https://spacenews.com/carlos-launch-vehicle-update-iac/)]

Bottom line: there's a lot, and all the numbers keep growing.

Comment: There's a paper by a  Carlos neiderstrasser which discusses the small sat launcher and their companies 

https://digitalcommons.usu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=4118&context=smallsat 

There is an updated version released at the smallsat conference 2019 but I dont have it with me. If this is Tim Dodd, great work man.. Fan of your work.